# How to make Safari remember my password for sites where autocomplete=off?

Tags: safari, password

Safari will remember my password on most sites, if I ask it to.  However, some "high-security" sites disable this functionality.  I want to override their override, and have Safari remember my password on that site -- even though the site doesn't want me to.

These "high-security" sites specify `autocomplete=off` in the HTML.  Most browsers will honor this and decline to remember your password, in that case.  For some browsers, like Firefox, folks have discovered ways to change this aspect of browser behavior and force the browser to remember your password, even on a site that uses `autocomplete=off`.  I know how to do it on Firefox, but that doesn't work on Safari. Yes, I do understand the security implications of doing this.

How do I make Safari remember my password for sites where autocomplete=off?

References:

- http://randosity.wordpress.com/2012/04/16/stupid-security-measures-autocompleteoff/
- http://www.howtogeek.com/62980/how-to-force-your-browser-to-remember-passwords/
- http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2010/06/10/safari-extension-autocomplete/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "autocomplete" extension in the third link works for me.

Here is a step-by-step recipe on how to install it, for others who may run into this:

1. Launch Safari.  In the menubar, click on Safari >> Preferences.  Under the Advanced pane, tick the box labelled "Show Develop menu in menu bar" at the bottom.
2. In the Safari menubar, you should now see Develop.  Click on Develop, then click on "Enable Extensions".
3. Download the extension from here: http://lapcatsoftware.com/downloads/autocomplete.safariextz
4. In your downloads folder, click on the file that you just downloaded.  Safari will ask you whether you want to install this extension.  Say yes.

Now you're good to go!

Answer (score 3):

Did you test the extension for Safari which you can download on the bottom of the third URL cited above?

http://lapcatsoftware.com/downloads/autocomplete.safariextz

I can install it w/o any problems in Safari 5.1.7. under Snow Leopard but could not test it due to lack of a site which uses autocomplete=off

Comment: If you happen to have a STEAM account, the community site (or the main site? Not sure right now) has autocomplete=off.

Answer (score 3):

Safari 7 allows overriding "autocomplete" in Password Preferences

[image]

Comment: Safari 7.0.3 doesn't have this option anymore

Comment: Yes, please use autocomplete extension as described in the answer by @D.W.

Comment: I came here looking for what happened to that option, because I used it once, and now it's gone. Sad day :(

Answer (score 2):

I use and recommend 1Password to store my passwords, but I've heard LastPass is another good password manager. Instead of storing your passwords in a single browser on a single computer, a password manager lets you use stored passwords in all of your browsers and syncs to all of your computers and devices (Mac, Win, iOS, Android).

https://agilebits.com/onepassword

Comment: Thanks.  Can you confirm whether 1Password will autofill passwords, even in forms that have the `autocomplete=off` attribute set? (That attribute normally presents most normal browser password managers from remembering or autofilling your password on those sites.)

Comment: Yes, it will. Confirmed with my bank site.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to successfully install the autocomplete script by Jeff Johnson (lapcatsoftware.com link above) on Safari 6 and it automatically filled in my credentials on the WHM control panel which was previously blocked.

Answer (score 0):

The bookmarklet in the second link (howtogeek.com link) doesn't work well for me.  The problem is you have to click the bookmarklet on the page everytime you want to log in (not just the first time you visit the page, but also every subsequent time you want it to fill in your password).  No good.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [TapIN](http://app.appsflyer.com/id554782625?c=appleForum&pid=forums) for that kind of sites. It's an alternative iOS excellent browser.

Answer (score -3):

Use Google chrome. It memorizes all passwords and auto fills them for you. Haven't gotten safari to do that for me on all the sites I want to yet.

Comment: That would be great if it were secure: http://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2013/08/08/chrome-firefox-display-plain-text-passwords-with-a-few-clicks/

Answer (score -3):

It is a bad idea to let your browser memorize all your password, especially the important ones.
It is easy to read stored passwords of any browser, even from Firefox password manager (https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-find-hidden-passwords-in-firefox/#comment-645841)

I would prefer to control which password is saved with my browser. But if you wanna stay really safe, use a password manager, online or offline.

I'm using Limitlesslane, which provides autosave, autofill and autologin features through a browser extension, available for all major browsers (except IE)