# Can I force Safari on iOS to store a password, though the site disallows it?

Tags: ios, safari, password, keychain

For OS X Safari [there is a solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59979/how-to-make-safari-remember-my-password-for-sites-where-autocomplete-off) to force storing of passwords. Some sites disallow the storing of passwords, and I wonder if I can force this, at least for some sites, on Safari on iOS 7.

Comment: May I know which site doesn't allow this function?

Comment: For example my cell phone provider, congstar. Safari tells me that this site disallows storing of passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it seems you can do this! I just found the settings under Safari->Passwords and auto-fill. The setting is called "always allow".

[image: AutoFill setting "Always Allow"]

Comment: Just note that the same option is also found on OS X. The only stipulation on both iOS and OS X is that you will need to enable a Lock Screen and Screen pass, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It happens that I do have a lock screen password.

Comment: This option is no longer present in iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Safari on iOS can't run extensions, and therefore functionality such as this can't be changed.

You can provide feedback to Apple regarding this at the following page:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/safari.html

Answer (score 0):

No to go around the question but you could always try a third party browser. I believe that chrome will let you do this.